# I am missing a return statement, not sure exactly why?

Tags: java, char, return

//I am missing a return statement here for some reason even though I am returning the correct type?

```
static char getOperator(String firstLine){  

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  
    firstLine = "Enter a valid operator (+ or - or *):";  
    System.out.println(firstLine);

    String doohickey = keyboard.nextLine();
    char operator = doohickey.charAt(' '); 

    if(operator=='+' && operator=='-' && operator=='*')
        return operator;
}
```

Comment: Well, what does it return if the user types an H?

Comment: Ummm, `doohickey.charAt(' ');`?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(operator=='+' && operator=='-' && operator=='*')
```

This condition will always be false in a single-threaded environment. Your operator can never be 3 values at evaluation.

In general, you need to provide a valid return type for all branches of your method. The compiler likely determined that this branch will not be hit, so that you need a return statement after the if-block.

Comment: That statement is **false** in all environments because `operator` is a local variable

Answer (score 1):

You are only returning a value if the condition is true. You have to return something or throw an exception for when the condition is not true. It becomes clearer when you surround the `if`-condition's block with braces. The `else` block was missing so not all branches actually returned a value.

Also this condition will never be true because your local variable can never be all three characters at the same time. Did you mean to write or's?

```
if(operator=='+' || operator=='-' || operator=='*')
{ 
    return operator; 
}
else
{ 
    throw new NotImplementedException(); 
}
```